# Disable Payment Gateway For Specific Shipping Method On Checkout Only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payment-method

I ran into an issue in WooCommerce and I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced it too.

I sell certain products that are too fragile to be shipped by UPS/DHL/FedEx. So I have to ship these products via pallet. To solve my problem I created a "request a quote" shipping method that allows my customers to select BACS as the payment method, request a quote as the shipping method and submit their orders. And after I have calculated the shipping costs, I update the order (change the shipping method to N/A) and change the status from "on-hold" to "pending payment" to allow the customer to pay by card if they wish to.

This is where I ran into the issue. I noticed that if I unset several payment gateways and if these certain shipping methods are selected, these payment gateways are not available to the customer in the "order-pay" endpoint (website/my-account/orders/) even if I remove the shipping method from the order.

Is there a way around this?

This is the code I am using to Disable Payment Gateway For Specific Shipping Method.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );

function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) { 

    $gateways_to_disable = array( 'cardgatecreditcard', 'cardgategiropay', 'cardgateideal', 'cardgatesofortbanking' );
    $shipping_methods = array( 'flat_rate', 'request_shipping_quote' );
    $disable_gateways = false;

    // Check if we need to disable gateways
    foreach ( $shipping_methods as $shipping_method ) {
        if ( strpos( WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0], $shipping_method ) !== false ) $disable_gateways = true;
    }
    
    // If so, disable the gateways
    if ( $disable_gateways ) {
        foreach ( $available_gateways as $id => $gateway ) {
            if ( in_array( $id, $gateways_to_disable ) ) {
                unset( $available_gateways[$id] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

**UPDATE** After consulting with a few developers they advised that this code runs every time Payment Gateways are required and suggested that I run this snippet only on the Checkout page.

They suggested adding the following to my code:

```
if ( is_checkout_pay_page() ) {
    // unset Payment Gateways
}
```

**SOLVED** Here's my attempt and it works. But not sure if it can we expressed better:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );

function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) { 

    if ( ! ( is_checkout_pay_page() ) ) {

    $gateways_to_disable = array( 'cardgatecreditcard', 'cardgategiropay', 'cardgateideal', 'cardgatesofortbanking' );
    $shipping_methods = array( 'flat_rate', 'request_shipping_quote' );
    $disable_gateways = false;

    // Check if we need to disable gateways
    foreach ( $shipping_methods as $shipping_method ) {
        if ( strpos( WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0], $shipping_method ) !== false ) $disable_gateways = true;
    }
    
    // If so, disable the gateways
    if ( $disable_gateways ) {
        foreach ( $available_gateways as $id => $gateway ) {
            if ( in_array( $id, $gateways_to_disable ) ) {
                unset( $available_gateways[$id] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
else { return $available_gateways;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );

function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) { 

    if ( ! ( is_checkout_pay_page() ) ) {

    $gateways_to_disable = array( 'paymentgateway1', 'paymentgateway2', 'paymentgateway3' );
    $shipping_methods = array( 'shippingmethod1', 'shippingmethod2', 'shippingmethod3' );
    $disable_gateways = false;

    // Check if we need to disable gateways
    foreach ( $shipping_methods as $shipping_method ) {
        if ( strpos( WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0], $shipping_method ) !== false ) $disable_gateways = true;
    }
    
    // If so, disable the gateways
    if ( $disable_gateways ) {
        foreach ( $available_gateways as $id => $gateway ) {
            if ( in_array( $id, $gateways_to_disable ) ) {
                unset( $available_gateways[$id] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
else { return $available_gateways;
    }
}
```